# Postman variables with unexpected breakline

Tags: curl, request, postman

Im trying to pass env. variables in postman request.

**#1, Original request:**

GET: `https://default-api.me/v1/get_this` <= This works fine

**#2 If Im setting up like this:**

GET: `{{baseUrl}}/v1/get_this` <= Not works

The difference in `cURL`is one breakline:

**#1** Curl:

```
1    curl --location --request GET 'https://default-api.me/api/v1/calendars' \
```

**#2** Curl:

```
1    curl --location --request GET 'https://default-api.me
2    /api/v1/calendars' \
```

In the #2 case there is a breakline exactly after the `{{baseUrl}}``

Any ideas, how can I remove that new line after the `env. variables`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your environment variable has a "\n" by mistake just remove everything and rewrite url:**

```
  https://default-api.me/api/v1/calendars
```

**and set the base url as :**

[image]

you can also set the environment variable as :

set url first as:

url:

```
  {{baseurl}}/api/v1/calendars
```

then in prerequest:

```
pm.environment.set("baseUrl","https://default-api.me")
```

you can also just reset the variable by removing the extra \n as:

```
pm.environment.set("baseurl",pm.environment.get("baseurl").replace("\n","").replace("\r",""))
```